# how to make a mail box system in minecraft with a hopper and command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

okay so i kinda wanna know how to make a hopper mail box system but im not sure how to make the command? so like what i want to do is when someone throws something into the hopper i want it to notify me that there is mail in my mail box because i think it would be very cool tbh and im realy new to command blocks and redstone and stuff sooo yee xD

Comment: For the future: Please try using better grammar and keeping only the necessary parts of your question (stuff like "because i think it would be very cool tbh and im realy new to command blocks and redstone and stuff sooo yee xD" is not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without command blocks, just put a chest under the hopper and run a comparator from the hopper to whatever you want to notify you, like a note block or redstone lamp.

Comment: In this configuration, comparator would only output a pulse as the item passes through the hopper and into the chest.

Comment: to make it constand, take the output from the chest

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic circuit to notify the presence of an item.  I used a chest but you can use a hopper if you like.

Comparator directly out of a chest.  Place one item in the chest and comparator outputs a signal of one:

[image: Basic]

Here is the same circuit but it shows that a comparator can be used through a block.  This could be used to have a mailbox outside the house and the indicator on the inside of the house.
[image: Through wall]

This is the same circuit as above but there is an item in the chest and a redstone lamp:
[image: Last]